# I need a regular expression that avoids letters and numbers in the same word

Tags: regex

```
Article (should pass)
Article45 (should not pass)
45 Article(should pass)
45Article(should not pass)
45 45 article article 45 45 45 article 45 article(should pass)
45 45 article article 45 45 45 article 45 45 article 45 45(should pass)
45 45 article article 45 45 45 article 45 article45(should not pass)
45articl45 yes 45(should not pass)
article 45 45 45 article(should pass)
```

Comment: Are you using python?

Comment: What @taurus05 wants to say is, per rules of [tag:regex] tag, "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: @taurus05, no I am not using python. Just a regex trick on c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line that does not contain a word that contains both a letter and a number.

```
^(?!.*(?=\w*[a-zA-Z])(?=\w*\d)).*$
```

[in action](https://regex101.com/r/LsxOv7/1) (but you may need to modify to match the specific regexp engine implementation, per my comment above)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to determine if there is no match than if there is a match. In Ruby,

```
r = /\p{L}\d|\d\p{L}/

"45 45 article 45 45 article 45 45" !~ r  #=> true
"45 45 article 45 45 article45"     !~ r  #=> false
```

In Ruby, `str !~ r` returns `true` if there is no match, the same as `!(str =~ r)`. The regular expression reads, "match a Unicode letter followed by a digit or a digit followed by a Unicode letter".